# "Empty" variables when dot-sourcing a config file in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

Am trying to setup a script with an external config file but not have luck gettin it to work:

I have a config file where i want to declare my variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
screenname=template
```

And my script where i am dotsourcing this file.

```
#!/bin/bash
. config.sh
echo $screenname

screen -S $screenname -X stuff "Test\015"
screen -S template -X stuff "Test\015"
```

Output:

```
template
No screen session found.
```

There is a screen with the name >template< and as you can see $screenname has the value of >template< but the first screen command still does return No screen session found...

Hope someone can help me with this stupid thing..
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `set -x` at the top of your script doing the "dotsourcing" (below the shebang line `#!/bin/bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
. config.sh
echo $screenname
:
rest of script
```

---

This will output each line as it's interpreted, before executing it and should assist you in trying to find out why it's not working. You may also want to add:

```
echo "[$screenname]"
echo "${#screenname]"
```

to get the delimited version and the length.

Some possibilities for the problem:

- May need to export the `screenname` variable (though I don't think so in this case since `bash` itself should interpret the environment variable).
- Some hidden characters in the variable.

Though, again, I stress you should perform the suggested steps to narrow down or locate the problem, rather than relying on guesswork.

Comment: Scripting in Windows is a bad idea ;D Thank you for this hint - it was a newline (+ screen -S $'template\r' -X stuff 'Test\015' -> No screen session found.)